# Xcode There is no XCFramework found on Flutter SDK Pluggin

Tags: swift, xcode, flutter, sdk, xcframework

I just merge from my old developer that already gone, he developing a feature using flutter and he put the SDK into the project, but I cannot run the project on my production env cause apparently the SDK doesn't have XCFramework for my production env, is there any way I can install or add this SDK XCFramework into my current production env?

this is what I got from my Xcode everytime i run the project on prod env[image]

can anyone knows how to solve this? or maybe how do i add this sdk plugin into my "Production" env to my project, cause the last developer embed this a long time ago and the code base have a lot of changes since then.

Thank you